# Problems finding the correct antiderivative

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

I am currently working on a problem of the course MIT 18.01SC Single Variable Calculus. The original problem can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=9&v=Psks_KK0YZ8) (you don't need to watch it, it's just the source).

The part I'm having trouble understanding is finding the following antiderivative:

$\int_0^{10} \frac{1500}{100 + (t-5)^2} - 7 dt$

The answer is given in the video, it's $\frac{1}{10} \Big( 150 \, \text{arctan}(\frac{t-5}{10}) - 7t \Big) \vert_{1}^{10}$.

However, I can't fully determine the steps needed to get to this solution. This is how far I get on my own:

1. Substitution, $u = t - 5, du = 1 dx$
2. This gives: $\int_{-5}^{5} \frac{1500}{100 + u^2} - 7 du = \int_{-5}^{5} 1500 \frac{1}{100 + u^2} - 7 du$
3. The antiderivative of $\frac{1}{1 + x^2} = \arctan x + c$

Questions:

- How do I get the integrand into the form $\frac{1}{1 + u^2}$? When dividing by $100$ I would get $\frac{1}{1 + \frac{u^2}{100}}$ which does not help either
- What further steps are missing?

Comment: You expect us to *watch a video* to see your question?

Comment: You have to change the limits of integration when you make a substitution.

Comment: The video is just a reference to the original problem. You don't need to watch it for understanding or answering the question.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, and I indicated where you went wrong in my next comment.

Comment: In step 2, the integral changes to -5 to 5.

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected the limits.

Comment: "which does not help either": though this hints a simple change of variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factoring out 100 in the denominator actually does help because you can rewrite 100 as 10^2 and then perform another substitution z=u/10. Now you can use your known antiderivative.
Edit:
[image: My solution]

Comment: Ok. So starting with $\int_{-5}^{5} \frac{1500}{100 + u^2} - 7 du$ I would first divide by 10 to get $\int_{-5}^{5} \frac{150}{10 + (u/10)^2} - 7 du$. Then I substitute $z = \frac{u}{10}, du = \frac{1}{10}$. But how does that give the final integral? Sorry I still don't see the answer

Comment: I will solve the exercise and upload it tomorrow, I’m busy now.

Comment: I added my solution to the problem, you misspelled the bounds in your desired solution, they should still be from 0 to 10, then my solution is equivalent to yours. I recommend using www.integral-calculator.com which has a function for checking whether your solution is equivalent to the correct one or WA to check your result numerically.

Comment: Thanks, now I got it!

Answer (score 0):

Substitute u/10 = tanx to get the desired form.

Answer (score 0):

When I see this problem, what I see is a number in the numerator divided by a number + a variable squared. That reminds me of the derivative of arctan. To bring it to that form, what you need is a 1 in the denominator. How do you do that? Just divide the numerator and denominator by 100. Next, try to think what you can substitute to get the square thingy in the denominator and it should be a piece of cake. ;)